# how to fix "no input files" in code::blocks code c++

Tags: c++

I installed `code::blocks` but I don't know why every project I open shows the message `"error; no input files"`. The name of the .cpp file has an lock, and I want to know how I open a folder of projects in it.

I searched and I couldn't find an answer probably because it is not a common issue.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

It's like the project doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: What permissions do you have for the Sources folder?

Comment: Have you only the project file? Does the cpp file you see locked in your project exist on your hard disk nearby the project file? Please list all existing files and folders recursvily which you see in your file system (i.e. not via codeblocks UI).

Comment: i dont know how to see the permisions, i have the entire folder, the folder "teste" inside him the bin and obj folder, and main.cpp, testes.cbp, testes.layout

Comment: What does it say in `settings -> compiler -> toolchain executables` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had no ascii characters in the project path. Once I had fixed this, it worked like charm.